# Where does one report VS2010 bugs to Microsoft?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Go to https://connect.microsoft.com and browse to 'Developer Tools' -> 'Visual Studio and Dotnet Framework' and the only entry there is Visual Studio 2012.

Enter 'Visual Studio 2010' in the 'Search for Products or Programs' search box and it returns 'There are no records that match the requested criteria.'

How can the bugs be posted to the relevant product?

Comment: Why would they have separate bug repos for different versions?

Comment: SO is not a rant blog. Please take the time to phrase questions in a more "neutral" manner.

Comment: @SLaks "Why not?" I've seen it both ways for different products... so I could see it being a [valid] initial assumption, even if not correct.

Comment: Imo different major releases of Visual Studio are different products not different versions of the same product. They are generally incompatible with each other, and MS certainly treats them as separate products when it comes to licensing.

Comment: @Neutrino: Microsoft treats different versions of _any_ product as having different licenses.  And VS2012 is now compatible with VS2010 projects.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio is Visual Studio.
Bugs in all versions are reported in the same place.

If you had followed your instructions, you would have noticed a version dropdown in the report form.

Comment: There is indeed. But the only version of Visual Studio listed is Visual Studio 2012.